# Undeclared delegate and shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webview, delegates, xcode5

i am newer to coding in general! I am trying to create a webview that doesnt allow navigation to viewers. I have most of the coding typed up, but i have two undeclared errors and i am not sure how to solve this issue.

What i am trying to do is create a webView, but i would like to make it where the viewer of the webView cant navigate to other pages. If he/she does attempt too it does not fulfill the request.So basically it stays specifically on one page.

If i just need declare them in a really simple way then please show me and help. Thank you.

The Errors are shown below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController()
<UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
webview:delegate = nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/u_bett"];
NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlrequest];

}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request         navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
return NO;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? `webview.delegate = nil;` and the other one is completely wrong, you can't call a method like that.

Comment: What i am trying to do is obviously create a webView, but i would like to make it where the viewer of the webView cant navigate to other pages. If he does attempt too it does not fulfill the request.So basically it stays specifically on one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method contains lot of issues:

Change that like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webview.delegate = self;  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/u_bett"];    
    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlrequest];

}
```

And implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` like:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Check this tutorial for [UIWebView implementation](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/21/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-1/).
I would like to suggest you to learn [Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) thoroughly before starting the development. (Some investment at this point will help you to save a lot of time in future)

Comment: I just did all of this and the undeclared identifier delegate error still shows. But the other is solved. what else should i do to fix the delegate error?

Comment: Did you add`<UIWebViewDelegate>` in your interface ? Also check the tutorial I provided in the answer

Comment: I just inserted my interface and lower into the question. i did but possibly not correctly.

Comment: @user2988372: where did you declared the `webview` I didn't see that in your interface ?

Comment: I just edited my exact code into the question. Thats what i have in the xcode now. The webview runs good. But im what im trying to do with the navigation to other cites with the viewer is my issue now.

Comment: @user2988372; are you using interface builder for connecting the UIWebView to your view ?

Comment: @user2988372: remove this `webview:delegate = nil;` and add `webview.delegate = nil;`

Comment: @user2988372: You are still using `webview:delegate = nil;` use `webview.delegate = nil;` instead

Comment: My mistake i didnt notice the subtle change. That does it Thank You!

Comment: @user2988372: with pleasure, also notice that use `webview.delegate = self;` instead of `webview.delegate = nil;` else the delegate methods won't be triggered.

Comment: I just tried changing it to self and it fails to load even the home page of the webview.

Comment: Yes it is loading now but you can still navigate all around twitter?